# How to connect to MongoDB in local network with express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm setting up a server with express and mongoose and I'd like it to be usable in other machines present in my local network. The bind_ip variable has already been set to 0.0.0.0 in the Mongodb configuration file.

```
const connection = mongoose
    .connect(
        "mongodb://192.168.254.104/db",
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true
        }
    )
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I've tried connecting on my mobile phone but the server response says it didn't find the database.

Comment: You're missing the port number and better to use localhost in most situations I think

Comment: Do you want to expose the mongodb server to your LAN? Because the code you're showing is server side code. Does that mean you want to run multiple express servers?

Comment: I only want them to use the same express server and database.

Comment: Right, in that case there's no need to expose the mongodb server to your LAN. Your express server is already reachable from all machines in your LAN, and only the express server needs to access the mongodb server. Since the two are on the same machine, there's no need for any special configuration stuff at all.

Comment: Hello, If your problem resolved, you should accept the answer and help the community.

Answer (score 9):

First, you should run a MongoDB server on Local.

Default running port is: 27017

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {
    dbName: 'event_db',
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
}, err => err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Connected to database'));
```

Or you can do

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/event_db');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the format of mongodb connection String:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

If you want to connect to a localhost database then the string would be like this:

```
"mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
```

Where "mydb" is the DB name on your local machine.

Comment: The connection URL ,which you provided in this example is wrong in this case ,because he is trying to connect to the local network , 192.168.X.X.

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
var mongooseOptions = {  useNewUrlParser: true }

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabase', mongooseOptions, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('System could not connect to mongo server.')
        console.log(err)     
    } else {
        console.log('System connected to mongo server.')
    }
});
```

Comment: The connection URL ,which you provided in this example is wrong in this case ,because he is trying to connect to the local network , 192.168.X.X.